# flex/bison returning a character token from the scanner in C++

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm using the calc++ example found in the bison documentation as a starting point to a more complex grammar. One thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to return a character (literal) token from flex to bison.

In pure C examples, I've seen flex simply returning the token as:

```
"+"         { count(); return('+'); }
```

The calc++ example simply uses token symbols:

```
"+"        return yy::parser::make_PLUS   (loc);
```

But this forces me to use PLUS instead of '+' in the grammar file.

How can I get flex to return a literal value as in the C example when generating C++ code?

Comment: You write the same code as in the C example.

Answer (score 1):

Do not define it at all. It will return as the literal and you will be able to use it in parser as '+'

Answer (score 0):

If you use "complete symbols" (that is, `%define api.token.constructor`), you should be able to use the appropriate `parser::symbol_type` constructor, as shown in the [bison manual section on "complete symbols"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Complete-Symbols):

```
":"      return yy::parser::symbol_type (':', loc);
```